# GeoDjango setup: ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, geocoding, postgis, geodjango

Update: thought I'd solved it, but I hadn't... please see below.

---

I'm installing GeoDjango on Mac OSX. I've followed the [Mac install instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#mac-os-x), which all went smoothly, and am now [creating a spatial database template for PostGIS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#creating-a-spatial-database-template-for-postgis).

However, when I try to load the PostGIS SQL routines, I get `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory`:

```
postgres$ psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql
psql:/usr/local/pgsql/share/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql:59: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory
<snip>
psql:/usr/local/pgsql/share/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql:7785: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
```

What's going wrong, and how can I fix it?

I found [these instructions from postgis IRC](http://logs.qgis.org/postgis/%23postgis.2010-03-12.log), but I think I'm running the right version of pg_config, etc:

```
postgres$ which pg_config
/usr/local/pgsql/bin//pg_config
postgres$ which psql
/usr/local/pgsql/bin//psql
postgres$ pg_config --pkglibdir
/usr/local/pgsql/lib
```

I installed postgres and its PostGIS extensions from [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres). If I look in `/usr/local/pgsql/lib`, there is a file called `postgis-1.5.so` there, so I don't understand why it's not being found.

Comment: That most probably is not the whole error message - there should be something before the "ERROR:  current transaction is aborted,...".

Comment: Yes, there is, sorry. The first error is: psql:/usr/local/pgsql/share/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql:59: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory (I've updated the question to show this).

Comment: You may find more expert answers to GIS related questions in the dedicated site http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I know this an old question, but i found it using Google, so others might end up here as well.

On my Mac OSX macports install, i had two folders with .so files for postgresql:

```
/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/
```

and

```
/usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/
```

It seems like my installation looked in /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/ and not in /usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/, so to install pg_trgm, i had to do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/pg_trgm.so /usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/
```

This should work with any .so file which is not in the right place - In your example it would have been

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/postgis-1.5.so /usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/
```

Which allows me to install postgis as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The file /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql9/9.0.17/lib/postgis-1.5.so is missing. This error happened after brew upgrade and the solution is to uninstall postgis and reinstall it with:

brew uninstall postgis15

brew install postgis15

The result should be: PostGIS plugin libraries installed to: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql9/9.0.17/lib

So afterwards you should find the file /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql9/9.0.17/lib/postgis-1.5.so